# "Open folder in new window" for Finder?

Tags: finder

In Finder, how do you open a folder in a new window, while the existing window keeps the same view?

All file managers I've ever used (on Linux only) have something like "Open folder in new window" in the right-click menu for a folder.  Does Finder have this feature in a hidden way, or is there another file manager I should be using on Mac?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key (Cmd) while double clicking the folder and it will open in a new Finder *Tab*.

In Finder Preferences, you can specify to open in a new window instead of a tab.

Comment: Interesting. It works, but often brings up two windows, one what I want, the other some other (random?) folder.

Comment: The Control key seems to do the same thing, but w/o the multiple windows coming up.

Comment: If you hold down Ctrl and click, you'll bring up the contextual menu. Cmd-key does work all times here. Maybe you accidentally selected two folders?

Comment: If i select several folder, Command+click brings up all. That was the problem. But still, Control+click brings up a new window just like I want, and no more even if other folders are selected.  For context menu, I right-click.

Comment: The Command key also works to select multiple non-contiguous items in a list, such as a list of folder items in a Finder window. What's likely happening is that you already had an item selecte din the Finder window and by Command-clicking the first time, you selected a second one. A way to avoid this is to single-click on the desired item first, so only that one is selected in the list, and *then* Command-double click it.

Comment: Also don't forget to switch off the option to open new folders in tabs in Finder Preferences if you switched it on.

Comment: Mac users. Use the mouse. Fcuk.

Answer (score 6):

Right-click on the folder, hold ⌥ (Option), and select "Open in New Window".

If you'd prefer this to be the default (and hold Option for a new tab instead), you can change it in Finder preferences.

Comment: This changes the "Open In New Tab" contextual menu item to "Open in New Window". In Finder Preferences, you can swap the two, so New Window is the default and option is held for New Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Command + Click on a folder opens what ever items you have selected in the current window. So if you have 3 folders selected, you will open each folder in a separate window - Annoying in some instances, but very useful in others.

Otherwise you can goto Finder > Preference and tick the "Always open folders in a new window" option.

Answer (score 0):

I typically would tap 2 fingers on the Finder, and choose "New Finder Window"
That is assuming you enable Two Finger tap to trigger Right Mouse Button click

Comment: This opens a new Finder window to the default location, at least for me.